# How to add link to a specific part of a 360 image in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, hyperlink, 360-degrees

I want to add a link to the TV in my 360 image that redirects the user to Youtube. How do I achieve that? Here is the webpage -- (https://bedroom69.netlify.app)[[image: Here is the screenshot]]
Here is the HTML Code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Beakball Bedroom</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="image-container"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/105/three.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-uWKImujbh9CwNa8Eey5s8vlHDB4o1HhrVszkympkm5ciYTnUEQv3t4QHU02CUqPtdKTg62FsHo12x63q6u0wmg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="js/panolens.min.js"></script>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Js,

```
const panoramaImage = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("images/image1.jpeg");
const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".image-container");

const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
  container: imageContainer,
  autoRotate: true,
  autoRotateSpeed: 0.3,
  controlBar: false,
});

viewer.add(panoramaImage);
```

Thank You.

I tried with mapping, like we do with 2d images in a webpage, but how to achieve in a 360 image in a webpage.
I tried like this,

```
<img src="image1.jpeg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="https://www.youtube.com/" coords="5010,1858,4658,1633" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="" shape="0">
</map>
```

But where to put it I can't figure out.

[image]
Like this in google maps